# Passing data to ViewController in Swift without segue

Tags: swift

I have two Controllers. One is just a Popover Frame. Its a small rectangle with a transparent background.

I have a Tableview in this second Controller and want to change a TextField in my first Controller through selecting a TableView Raw in my second Controller.

Is it possible? This the method from my first Controller which will create the second Controller / CategoryViewController:

```
@IBAction func showCategoryPopup(_ sender: Any) {
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "categoryVC") as! CategoryViewController
        self.addChild(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

And this is the method which will create the Popover in my second Controller:

```
func showAnimate() {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3,y:1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.0,y:1.0)
        }
    }

    func removeAnimate() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3,y:1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (finished: Bool) in
            if(finished) {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i call my first Controller from the second Controller? I tried this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

//        let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "changeBalanceCtrl") as! ChangeBalanceViewController

        let firstVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "changeBalanceCtrl") as! ChangeBalanceViewController


        firstVC.changeBalanceTextField.text! = "TEST"

    }
```

I think the problem is that the first Controller changeBalanceTextField.text is nil. 
I checked out the 'self' parameter and i got two different objects. So i think the first Controller which i build with my second Controller is a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do with the `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` in the table view delegate is creating a new instance of ChangeBalanceViewController. To access the actual parent of the second view controller you need to use `self.parent` in the second view controller.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let firstVC = self.parent as? ChangeBalanceViewController {
        firstVC.changeBalanceTextField.text = "TEST"
    }
}
```